# Does one woman can open and allow to touch other woman's her breast ??it is halal or haram?

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam, women, sunni

As if a girl open up her breast in front of other girl and allow her close best friend to touched her breast?? It is halal or haraam?

Comment: Why would this occur?  A medical check up?  Youth comparing body parts?  Something sexual?

Comment: For any wish, or in front of sisters else or in front of room mate or best friends ???

Comment: It is permissible in islam to do this???

Comment: Nope. In Islam the awrah is to be completely covered except when in front of the spouse, very young children, slaves and in case of medical emergencies. The awrah for men is from "below belly button to the knees" and for women is her whole body except the face, hands and feet.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not permissible. This is haram and a major sin. You are not allowed to show your private parts to anyone other than your parents and legal spouse, or to your doctor for health and medical reasons, its haram even if it's your best friend.

Answer (score 0):

It is permissible for a woman to see and touch the breasts of fellow women (excluding non-Muslim women), provided it is not with intention of lust. The awrah of a woman in front of another woman, is her private parts (vulva and anus) according to Shias or the area between navel and knees according to Sunnis.

Breasts are "zeenah" (beauty or charms) of a woman which she can expose in front of Muslim women according to the following verse of Quran :

"And tell the believing women to lower their glances and guard their private parts and not expose their beauty except only that which is apparent and to wrap [a portion of] their headcovers over their chests and not expose their beauty except to their husbands, their fathers, their husbands’ fathers, their sons, their husbands’ sons, their brothers, their brothers’ sons, their sisters’ sons, **their women**, that which their right hands possess, or those male attendants having no physical desire, or children who are not yet aware of the private aspects of women. And they should not strike their feet, drawing attention to their hidden charms. And turn to Allāh in repentance, all of you, O Believers, that you might succeed." [Sura an-Nur 24:31]